# Detect cookie expiry on Android web view

Tags: android, android-webview, android-cookiemanager

I am setting cookies from android  side with an expiry time. But I want to detect when cookie expire is there a event fire from android web view?

Comment: Anyone??can help :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get cookies from webview with path and expiration date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40981021/get-cookies-from-webview-with-path-and-expiration-date)

Comment: @HemantParmar ok I wanna know from which we know cookie has expired or not ?