# Android WebView get raw cookie information

Tags: cookies, android-webview, webviewclient, android-cookiemanager

I try to get cookie information with CookieManager in Android WebView. However, all it does is providing a key value pair of cookies, no additional information.

I also tried this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40981021/get-cookies-from-webview-with-path-and-expiration-date/41121660) and use `connection.getHeaderFields.get("Set-Cookie");` to get all cookies received from server. But from what I can tell, I don't see all cookies that I am supposed to receive from server. This can also be found by some cookies in CookieManger receive a new value but not show in `Set-Cookie` field.

Ideally, I would like to intercept every response and inspect their cookies with all information from server such as name, value, max-age, secure, etc. Any suggestion how to do this with Android WebView (WebViewClient)?